# Creating an author archive page in wp. Strugging to display author meta

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
<?php
$authors = get_authors();
$jobTitle = get_the_author_meta('job_title');
foreach ($authors as $author)
{ 
?>
<div>
    <h1><?= $author->display_name; ?></h1>
    <h2><?= $jobTitle ?></h2>
</div> 
<?php
} ?>
```

Bit of a noob question here, but having some difficulty.  Using get_authors to return the array of the wp author roles for a wp author archive page, on the front end its able to retrieve the values from the array such as name, email etc but I'm not able to return author meta such as avatar or job title.

Anyone have any idea how this can be achieved?

I can see that the array does not contain things like the author meta but how can I return the author meta for each author inside of the array individually

Answer (score 1):

Quick update as I have now figured this out myself so just wanted to post an answer! Apologies for wasting anyones time my bad! Needed to pass the ID in to the variable and move it inside the loop

```
<?php
$authors = get_authors();

foreach ($authors as $author) {
$jobTitle = get_the_author_meta('job_title', $author->ID); // Retrieve job title for each author

// Now you can use $jobTitle to display the individual author's job title
?>
<div>
    <h1><?= $author->display_name; ?></h1>
    <h2><?= $jobTitle ?></h2>
</div> 
<?php
}
?>
```